# Grafana, how to choose which column for axis in Timechart?

Tags: grafana, appinsights

I am using Grafana to perform a Log to Metric query using an Azure Data Explorer datasource,  that gives me a result like this as a table:
[image]

This comes from this query:

```
Log
| where $__timeFilter(TIMESTAMP)
| where eventId == 666
| summarize count() by bin(TIMESTAMP, 15m), Region
| order by TIMESTAMP asc
```

When rendered as a timechart in AppInsights, it renders perfectly like this:

[image]

However in Grafana, this perplexingly renders by the Count_ column, not using the obvious Regional breakout field:

[image]

My goal is to get an AppInsight's like timechart with multiple data series, within Grafana

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer!  It turns out I was rendering the data as a Table, using the Grafana query wizard here.

[image]

Once I changed that to **TimeSeries**, it all *just worked!*

[image]
[image]